# Calculating Circumference and Area of Circle With Javascript - Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, math, geometry

I'm trying to create a simple javascript application that will ask the user to enter the radius of a circle, and in return will display the circumference and area in sentence form after the user hits "Calculate". Right now, when the user enters a number and hits "calculate", nothing happens.

The JavaScript is included in the HTML document like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <title>Create a Circle</title>
  <h1 style="text-align:center">Create a Circle!</h1>
  <br>
  <div style="text-align:center">
  Enter the radius for your circle:
  <input type="text" id="txtRadius" size="10" />
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="CalculateArea()"/>

  <script>

  function print() {
    var p = 
    document.createElement("p"),
    text = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments,",");
    p.textContent = text;
    document.getElementById("console").appendChild(p);
    return text;    
  }

  function CalculateCircumference() {
    var radius =
    parseInt(document.getElementById('txtRadius').value);//String to Integer

    if (0 < radius)
        print("The circumference of the circle is " + (radius * 2 * Math.PI);
    else
        print("Error - radius must be a whole number greater than 0.");
    return false;
  }

  function CalculateArea() {
    var radius = 
    parseInt(document.getElementById('txtRadius').value); //String to Integer

    if (0 < radius)
        print("The area of the circle is " + (radius * radius * Math.PI);
    else
        print("Error - radius must be a whole number greater than 0.");
    return false;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>   
</html>
```

I'm new to the print method so I tried changing all prints to "alert", but this didn't do anything. Thank you for your help. Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/xzsf8ca4/2/

Comment: I don't know but maybe you will do  radius > 0, otherwise  zero is always less then radius

Comment: That didn't do anything unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, don't use 'print' - this prints the current page (litterally)! Try naming your function something else - like pPrint

Comment: Your code is just buggy, and needs to be cleaned up before it can be diagnosed properly. Twice you call a method without closing the parenthesis (`print("The circumference of the circle is " + (radius * 2 * Math.PI);` and `print("The area of the circle is " + (radius * radius * Math.PI);`), and when you write `document.getElementById("console").appendChild(p);` where exactly is `console` defined?

Comment: You're right it should be "txtRadius" instead of console. Now I tried adding the parentheses but still not working. Please see updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/xzsf8ca4/5/ - still nothing happening.

Comment: @user3546086 look at my answer, I have a working fiddle for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have more issues with your code however this will answer your question

The reason nothing happens is because you are missing a `)` and is makeing the function invalid.

change this: `print("The area of the circle is " + (radius * radius * Math.PI);`

to this: `print("The area of the circle is " + (radius * radius * Math.PI));`

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xzsf8ca4/4/

Comment: Thank you. Still not displaying area and circumference though.

Comment: LOL! yeah, you have quite a bit of problems with the code. I was just getting you back on track. If you have any other questions though, feel free to post another question and we all will help you out.

Comment: Okay, yeah I just need the alert to show the area and circumference. Thanks.

Comment: Yep that's it. So you just added both alerts/calculations to the same if statement. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, makes it easier.

Comment: Just curious, what if you don't want a dialog box? What method would you use if you just want the text to appear on the page?

Comment: This will do it for you http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createtextnode.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
function CalculateCircumference() {
    var radius =
    parseInt(document.getElementById('txtRadius').value);//String to Integer

    if (radius > 0)
        //calculate
    else
        //error
    return false;
  }
```